# Is there a shortcut for dropping, creating and importing a database using pg_restore ?

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I'm currently doing this a lot

```
dropdb app
createdb -O app app
pg_restore -d app ~/backup/app_backup.dump
```

I saw `pg_restore` has a `-C` option but it does not include dropping the database, just create it. `-c` drops the objects but it always get's tangled.

Obviously I can write a short script to do it but I was just wondering if `pg_resotre` already have this option.

Comment: Is everything in that database owned by the same user?

Comment: Yes. The owner is app.

Comment: Then you could do `drop owned by app` before restoring the dump. That will drop _everything_ that is **owned** by the user `app`.

Comment: That's not the problem. I can just as well dropdb ...  I though there might be a pg_restore flag to do that. It seems like a fairly common task.